# MacPorts - Installing Port, Dependencies Failed

Tags: macos, macports, xulrunner

I am attempting to install **xulrunner** on OSX 10.6.3 using the following:

```
sudo port install xulrunner
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
nat-10-200-136-126:phoneyc-new $ sudo port install xulrunner
--->  Computing dependencies for xulrunner
--->  Activating zlib @1.2.5_0
Error: The following dependencies failed to build: gconf dbus-glib glib2 zlib gtk-doc             docbook-xml docbook-xml-4.1.2 xmlcatmgr docbook-xml-4.2 docbook-xml-4.3 docbook-xml-4.4     docbook-xml-4.5 docbook-xml-5.0 docbook-xsl gnome-doc-utils iso-codes libxslt libxml2 p5-xml-parser py26-libxml2 python26 bzip2 db46 gdbm openssl readline sqlite3 tk Xft2 fontconfig freetype xrender xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-renderproto tcl xorg-libXScrnSaver xorg-libXext xorg-scrnsaverproto rarian getopt intltool gnome-common p5-getopt-long p5-pathtools p5-scalar-list-utils gtk2 atk cairo libpixman libpng jasper jpeg pango shared-mime-info tiff xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-libXdamage xorg-damageproto xorg-libXi xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto orbit2 libidl policykit heimdal lcms libcanberra gstreamer bison flex gzip texinfo lzmautils libvorbis libogg libnotify nss xorg-libXt xorg-libsm xorg-libice
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

Before reporting a bug, first run the command again with the -d flag to get complete output.
nat-10-200-136-126:phoneyc-new$

I am unsure how to correct this issue, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: To debug, try installing the depencies on the first error line one at a time (either manually or using xargs)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running with the -d flag?

You'd probably be best served by running:

```
sudo port install gconf
sudo port dbus-glib
etc
```

to see which exactly is breaking.

However, it might be possible this is using some Linux only code that might not be available in Mac OS X